# Date format in JavaScript. For example: June 10, 2021

Tags: javascript

How do I can set the date format to "June 10, 2021"?
I have a small piece of code like this:

```
var homnay = new Date();
        var datehomnay = (homnay.getMonth()+1) + ' ' + homnay.getDate() + ', ' + homnay.getFullYear();
        document.getElementById("curDay").innerHTML = datehomnay;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34015511/6299168 please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this procedure

```js
const MONTHS = ['JANUARY', 'FEBRUARY', 'MARCH', 'APRIL', 'MAY', 'JUNE', 'JULY', 'AUGUST', 'SEPTEMBER', 'OCTOBER', 'NOVEMBER', 'DECEMBER']

const date = new Date()

const dateString = `${MONTHS[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getDate()}, ${date.getFullYear()}`

console.log(dateString)
```